# Vim: running `:Explore` (netrw) results in "E492: Not an editor command: Explore"

Tags: macos, vim, homebrew, neovim, netrw

I can't use `:Explore`, `:Sexplore`, et al in both vim or neovim. When I try, I get `E492: Not an editor command: Explore`.

I know it's a problem with my vimrc, because `:Explore` works when I run [`vim -u empty_file`](https://explainshell.com/explain?cmd=vim+-u).

So, **which configuration/plugin is breaking netrw?**

Here's my [vimrc](https://github.com/sh78/dotfiles/blob/399f79134c0be0c3e025181db28961d85ec82a23/.vimrc#L1), which is sourced in nvim's [init.vim](https://github.com/sh78/dotfiles/blob/399f79134c0be0c3e025181db28961d85ec82a23/.config/nvim/init.vim#L1).

Yes, I know - I have a lot of plugins. I'm a recent convert and just playing the field to see what's worth keeping.

Vim and nVim were installed via homebrew and I believe they are latest stable. Here's the build info for both vim and nvim:

```
> vim --version
VIM - Vi IMproved 8.1 (2018 May 17, compiled May 22 2018 22:51:49)
macOS version
Included patches: 1
Compiled by Homebrew
Huge version without GUI.  Features included (+) or not (-):
+acl               +farsi             +mouse_sgr         -tag_any_white
+arabic            +file_in_path      -mouse_sysmouse    -tcl
+autocmd           +find_in_path      +mouse_urxvt       +termguicolors
-autoservername    +float             +mouse_xterm       +terminal
-balloon_eval      +folding           +multi_byte        +terminfo
+balloon_eval_term -footer            +multi_lang        +termresponse
-browse            +fork()            -mzscheme          +textobjects
++builtin_terms    -gettext           +netbeans_intg     +timers
+byte_offset       -hangul_input      +num64             +title
+channel           +iconv             +packages          -toolbar
+cindent           +insert_expand     +path_extra        +user_commands
-clientserver      +job               +perl              +vertsplit
+clipboard         +jumplist          +persistent_undo   +virtualedit
+cmdline_compl     +keymap            +postscript        +visual
+cmdline_hist      +lambda            +printer           +visualextra
+cmdline_info      +langmap           +profile           +viminfo
+comments          +libcall           -python            +vreplace
+conceal           +linebreak         +python3           +wildignore
+cryptv            +lispindent        +quickfix          +wildmenu
+cscope            +listcmds          +reltime           +windows
+cursorbind        +localmap          +rightleft         +writebackup
+cursorshape       -lua               +ruby              -X11
+dialog_con        +menu              +scrollbind        -xfontset
+diff              +mksession         +signs             -xim
+digraphs          +modify_fname      +smartindent       -xpm
-dnd               +mouse             +startuptime       -xsmp
-ebcdic            -mouseshape        +statusline        -xterm_clipboard
+emacs_tags        +mouse_dec         -sun_workshop      -xterm_save
+eval              -mouse_gpm         +syntax
+ex_extra          -mouse_jsbterm     +tag_binary
+extra_search      +mouse_netterm     +tag_old_static
   system vimrc file: "$VIM/vimrc"
     user vimrc file: "$HOME/.vimrc"
 2nd user vimrc file: "~/.vim/vimrc"
      user exrc file: "$HOME/.exrc"
       defaults file: "$VIMRUNTIME/defaults.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/share/vim"
Compilation: clang -c -I. -Iproto -DHAVE_CONFIG_H   -DMACOS_X -DMACOS_X_DARWIN  -g -O2 -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1
Linking: clang   -L. -fstack-protector -L/usr/local/lib -L/usr/local/opt/libyaml/lib -L/usr/local/opt/openssl/lib -L/usr/local/opt/readline/lib  -L/usr/local/lib -o vim        -lncurses -liconv -framework AppKit   -mmacosx-version-min=10.13 -fstack-protector-strong -L/usr/local/lib  -L/usr/local/Cellar/perl/5.26.2/lib/perl5/5.26.2/darwin-thread-multi-2level/CORE -lperl -lm -lutil -lc  -L/usr/local/opt/python/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/3.6/lib/python3.6/config-3.6m-darwin -lpython3.6m -framework CoreFoundation  -lruby.2.5.1 -lobjc

> nvim -v
NVIM v0.2.2
Build type: Release
LuaJIT 2.0.5
Compilation: /usr/local/Homebrew/Library/Homebrew/shims/super/clang -Wconversion -U_FORTIFY_SOURCE -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=1 -DNVIM_MSGPACK_HAS_FLOAT32 -DNVIM_UNIBI_HAS_VAR_FROM -DNDEBUG -DMIN_LOG_LEVEL=3 -Wall -Wextra -pedantic -Wno-unused-parameter -Wstrict-prototypes -std=gnu99 -Wimplicit-fallthrough -Wvla -fstack-protector-strong -fdiagnostics-color=auto -DINCLUDE_GENERATED_DECLARATIONS -I/tmp/neovim-20180209-92407-udkzoo/neovim-0.2.2/build/config -I/tmp/neovim-20180209-92407-udkzoo/neovim-0.2.2/src -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/include -I/usr/local/opt/gettext/include -I/usr/include -I/tmp/neovim-20180209-92407-udkzoo/neovim-0.2.2/build/src/nvim/auto -I/tmp/neovim-20180209-92407-udkzoo/neovim-0.2.2/build/include
Compiled by brew@HighSierra.local

Features: +acl +iconv +jemalloc +tui
See ":help feature-compile"

   system vimrc file: "$VIM/sysinit.vim"
  fall-back for $VIM: "/usr/local/Cellar/neovim/0.2.2_1/share/nvim"

Run :checkhealth for more info
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, on a hunch, it turns out [ranger.vim](https://github.com/rafaqz/ranger.vim) is the culprit.